# Sumo and NS-2 integration using TraCI

Tags: c++, xml, makefile, tcl, ns2

I'm trying to integrate sumo and NS2 using TraCI, but I can't find the error.
Commands:

> `sumo-gui -n /home/user/Desktop/sumo/map.net.xml --remote-port 8888 &`
>   `ns simulation.tcl`

This opens the SUMO interface and the map is opened with no problems, but when I try to start the simulation it returns:

> `Loading net-file from '/home/user/Desktop/sumo/map.net.xml'...done(1142ms).`
>   `Loading done.`
>   `Simulation started with time: 0.00`
>   `Error: Requested command not implemented (1): Command not implemented in sumo`
>   `Error: tcpip::Socket::recvAndCheck @ recv: peer shutdown`
>   `Quitting (on error).`

In Terminal this message appears:

> `Error in method TraCIClient::extractCommandStatus, Server returned error [] Command not implemented in sumo`

Versions used:
SUMO sumo Version 0.17.1
NS-2 Version 2.34
Ubuntu 12.04

After some changes and patches(TraCI), it returns a bunch of error on the make command, for example:

> `traci-client/TraCIClient.o:TraCIClient.cc:function TraCIClient::connect(): error: undefined reference to 'tcpip::Socket::connect()'`

Can someone point what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing that there's a Tcl command that isn't implemented for some reason, and that the command isn't a core feature of Tcl or its standard library. Which isn't very much help to you! (I don't know SUMO or NS2.)

Comment: The [Storage& s] is used to:  [unsigned char result = s.readChar()] which is meant to be 0(RTYPE_OK). The program tries to compare 0 with a rectangle with 4 numbers inside(couldn't paste here). Since the comparison returns false, the program aborts.